# HTML5 Rendering performance report

Tags: html, performance

Are there any tools that can give performance reports on HTML5 **rendering**. If so can the tool be automated as soon as development finishes and the user can get the performance report so that he can compare it with the previous values.

We require the tool to get the NFR metrics for benchmarking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML5 supports a WebTimings API but this gives a good first intro to the topic: http://www.yottaa.com/blog/bid/215492/Using-Web-Timing-API-To-Measure-Page-Performance.

There is a Chrome demo at http://webtimingdemo.appspot.com/